# Upload file to S3 with Ansca Corona SDK

Tags: upload, amazon-s3, lua, coronasdk

Does anyone know a way to upload image files directly from a Corona app to an Amazon S3 bucket?  I found  this article helpful on how to upload to a server by base64 encoding the image first:

http://developer.anscamobile.com/code/how-upload-image-server-multipartform-data

To my knowledge though, this method will not work uploading directly to S3.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and implemented S3 support myself.  See:

http://developer.anscamobile.com/code/amazon-s3-rest-api-implementation-corona

Note that there are a lot of caveats (it uses blocking I/O, which is kind of a non-starter, and the async I/O provided by Corona doesn't have enough functionality/fidelity to talk to the S3 REST API, at least not yet).

Comment: I updated this module to support asynchronous IO, so it now has fewer caveats.